# the program will not tell if the user won or lost it just keeps on saying they tied

Tags: python, function, easygui

```
import easygui
from easygui import *
import random
import sys
compscore = 0
playerscore = 0
for i in range(0,5):
    def gamerules():
        msgbox ('For this game you must choose one of the option to batle against your optonint')
    def player_choice():
        msg = ('Rock, Paper, Scissors')
        title = ('Choose your action')
        choices =['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
        choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)
        if choice =='Rock':
            msgbox('You chose Rock', image = 'sizzors_gif.gif')
        elif choice == 'Paper':
            msgbox('You chose Paper', image = 'paer_gif.gif')
        elif choice == 'Scissors':
            msgbox('You chose Scissors', image = 'source.gif')
        return msgbox
    def computer_choice():
        msg = ('the computer choose')
        title = ('computer turn')
        computer_choice = [ 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Sizzors' ]
        computer = (random.sample(computer_choice, 1))
        compchoice = (computer)
        choice = buttonbox(msg, title, compchoice)
        if choice == 'Sizzors':
            msgbox('computer choose rock:', image = 'source.gif')
            sizzors = 'sizzors'
            return sizzors
        elif choice == 'Rock':
            msgbox('computer choose sizzors :', image = 'sizzors_gif.gif')
            rock = 'rock'
            return rock
        elif choice == 'Paper':
            msgbox('computer choose paper :', image = 'paer_gif.gif')
            paper = 'paper'
            return paper


    def roundwinner(player,computer, compwinner, playerwinner):
        if player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
                msgbox('you lost the point goes to the computer')
                compwinner = compwinner + 1
        elif computer == 'sizzors': 
                msgbox("You win!", "continue", image = 'Ghuman_winner.gif')
                playerwinner = playerwinner + 1
        else:
                msgbox ('you and the computer tied no point is rewarded', "continue")
        if player == "Paper" and computer == "Scissors":
                msgbox ("You lose!", computer, "continue", player)
                compwinner = compwinner + 1
        elif computer  == 'rock':
                msgbox ("You win!", player, "continue", computer)
                playerwinner = playerwinner + 1
        if player == "Scissors":
            if computer == "Rock":
                msgbox ("You lose...", computer, "continue", player)
                compwinner = compwinner + 1
            else:
                msgbox ("You win!", player, "continue", computer)
                playerwinner = playerwinner + 1

move = player_choice()
computermove = computer_choice()
winner = roundwinner (move, computermove, compscore, playerscore )
```

Comment: Why are you defining functions _within_ the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put function definition into `for` loop (because only the last one will remain); Instead, put those last lines in the for loop:

```py
for i in range(5):
    move = player_choice()
    computermove = computer_choice()
    winner = roundwinner (move, computermove, compscore, playerscore )
```

In addition, you don't need to specify `0` in `for i in range(0, 5)`; `for i in range(5)` will do the same.

#### Edit

```py
def player_choice():
    msg = ('Rock, Paper, Scissors')
    title = ('Choose your action')
    choices =['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
    choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)
    if choice == 'Rock':
        msgbox('You chose Rock', image='sizzors_gif.gif')
    elif choice == 'Paper':
        msgbox('You chose Paper', image='paer_gif.gif')
    elif choice == 'Scissors':
        msgbox('You chose Scissors', image='source.gif')
    return choice
```

Comment: I did that and yet it still doesn't tell the user if it won or loss

Comment: I haven't use `easygui` package very much, but I thing you should return `choice` at the end of your `player_choice` function. Check edit and let me know if there is any issues.

Comment: I did that and still, It did not tell the user if it won or lost

Comment: What _exactly_ happens? Is there any error, Or there is just no output message? Also consider moving `roundwinner (move, computermove, compscore, playerscore)` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: it gives no message